# Как из второй активити вернуться в первую, при этом пересоздав первую?

Tags: android, kotlin, activity-life-cycle

Имеется приложения с 3 экранами. Экран А- главный и два вспомогательных - Б и С.
В экране Б я изменяю тему приложения, но возвращаюсь к главному экрану и вижу что изменения не применились. Иду дальше в С и там они применились, даже если перед этим всем зайти в С.
Так как setTheme находится везде в onCreate,то логично предположить(дебаг подтверждает), что onCreate первой самой активити - экрана А не применяется заново.

1. Как сделать так, что бы при возврате из второй активити в первую(Б->A) у меня применялся метод onCreate(полное пересоздание активити)?
   2)Почему С ведёт себя так как будто она пропадает из стэка активити? Ведь по логике если я зашел в С, потом пошёл поменял тему в Б через А. то при возврате в С тоже не должен onCreate применяться.

Я допёр до чего-то такого - при вызове Б я делаю так:

```
intentSettings.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
intentSettings.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
```

и в Б переопределяю onBackPressed так что бы заново вызывалась активити А.
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете просто повторно использовать `Intent`, который создал нужную вам `Activity`. Создаейте в вашей `Activity` переменную

```
Intent intent;
```

а в `onCreate ()`, присвойте ей значение

```
starterIntent = getIntent();
```

После того как вы захотите пересоздать вашу `Activity` вызовите

```
finish(); 
startActivity(starterIntent);
```

Это не очень элегантное решение и я думаю, что корень вашей проблемы в другом месте, но это простой способ перезапустить свою `Activity` и заставить ее перезагрузить все.

Comment: Активити А создаётся без интента, это главный экран. Обновлять активити А надо после возврата из Б. Если я правильно всё понял в вашем ответе

Comment: Activity A так же создается через Intent, разница в том, что вы его руками не создаете, а он создается системой за вас

Comment: Да, теперь я вас понял. Сделал, но в таком случае появляется анимация подгрузки неприятная.Да, появляется анимация довольно неприятная, которая портит картину,но всё равно благодарю

Comment: НУ анимацию тоже можно поменять. `Activity.overridePendingTransition()` вот этим методом. Попробовать побаловаться. но как я уже сказал, это костыль и мне кажется вам нужно решение на более высоком уровне. Потому что перезапустить активити это не оч хорошая идея

Comment: пробовал уже) Понимаю что перезапускать не разумно. Как я понимаю, вернуться по стэку назад с обновлением layout активити А возможности нет? мне же для смены темы по сути только сделать setContentView надо. Хотя это и равняется перезапуску активити насколько я знаю

Comment: Ну чтоб сменить тему нужно в любом случае перезапустить приложение. Круто если вы перезапустите его и восстановите стек экранов. Если вас интересует поведение как в Telegram то там вам вероятно придется ой как сильно заморочиться. Потому что из коробки такого решения нет.

Comment: Я на лету и пытаюсь сделать,  3 экрана же всего. Но вот наблюдаю,что вы правы. Надо перезапускать, либо с тормозами в виде перезапуска активити заморачиваться,но тут тормоза.

Comment: Я никогда не делал на лету, но как мне кажется тут просто нужно красить UI элементы руками. А значит у вас должен быть какой-то флаг который и отвечает за цвет темы. И где-нибудь в `onResume()` вам постоянно надо его чекать

Comment: ну вот я попробовал через setColorFilter и setBackgroundColor поменять в onRestart а не в onResume. Но муть какая-то вышла, синий фон вместо черного получился. Завтра ещё поразбираюсь , если не выйдет - буду с перезагрузкой смену темы делать.Спасибо